# Rewrite Rule for default post type

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I am using two post types into my site:
a) Post ( default post type )
b) Program ( Custom Post Type )
I am trying to add '/blog/' string to default post type URL. If I am tying to do it from permalink option in admin panel then it will aslo add the string to Program post type but I want it as following:

a) example.com/blog/post-name/
b) example.com/program/program-name/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is controlled by your post type registration code, please edit your question and add your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register your custom post type using [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function, you have to be very careful with [`rewrite`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite) param.

You should pass an array with following keys:

> - **slug** => string Customize the permalink structure slug. Defaults to
>     the $post_type value. Should be translatable.
> - **with_front** => bool
>     Should the permalink structure be prepended with the front base.
>     (example: if your permalink structure is /blog/, then your links will
>     be: false->/news/, true->/blog/news/). Defaults to true
> - **feeds** =>
>     bool Should a feed permalink structure be built for this post type.
>     Defaults to has_archive value.
> - **pages** => bool Should the permalink
>     structure provide for pagination. Defaults to true
> - **ep_mask** => const
>     As of 3.4 Assign an endpoint mask for this post type. For more info
>     see Rewrite API/add_rewrite_endpoint, and Make WordPress Plugins
>     summary of endpoints. If not specified, then it inherits from
>     permalink_epmask(if permalink_epmask is set), otherwise defaults to
>     EP_PERMALINK.

In your case, setting `with_front` to false for your CPT should solve your problem.

Comment: "In your case, setting with_front to false for your CPT should solve your problem." This point help me and fix my issue. Thanks foir help. As I am new here so plz let em know how can I make it solved!

Comment: @PardeepSingh You have to click on the tick sign near the answer that helped you. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234